# send an email after adding x headers in logic app azure or power app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, powerapps

I am open to use any azure service like Logic app or power app. What I am trying to do is add some custom x header and then sent out email . Is there a way to do this ?

In this flow, I read a file from azure storage blob and send it out with the file as an attachment to the email. I want to add custom x header to the email before sending out the attachment. This is the step where I am stuck

[image]

I am adding more flavor as it looks to me my question was not clear to some of you guys. Thanks a lot in advance.
I looked at Send an email (v2) don't see any option to add/change x-headers

[image]

Custom x header that i want to add are as bellow
[image]

Comment: You can try sending the email via Graph API where you can add headers. Look for `internetMessageHeaders` under [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) and [user: sendMail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Answer (score 0):

You can call an azure function to send the email for you

```
using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage())
                {
                mailMessage.Headers.Add("X-Custom-Header1", "Header1 Value");
                mailMessage.Headers.Add("X-Custom-Header2", "Header2 Value");

                // Other email data and send the email
            }
```